# pct_change with multindex in python

Tags: python, stock

Imagine I have a dataframe with multindex (stock and date). I would like to calculate the pct_change from column close. I use this code:

```
data['win'] = data.Close.pct_change()*100

        Open    Close   High    Low Volume  Adj_Close   win
Ticker  Date                            
AAPL    2018-12-14  169.000000  165.479996  169.080002  165.279999  40703700    165.479996  NaN
2018-12-17  165.449997  163.940002  168.350006  162.729996  44287900    163.940002  -0.930622
2018-12-18  165.380005  166.070007  167.529999  164.389999  33841500    166.070007  1.299259
2018-12-19  166.000000  160.889999  167.449997  159.089996  48889400    160.889999  -3.119171
AMZN    2018-12-14  1638.000000 1591.910034 1642.569946 1585.000000 6367200 1591.910034 **889.440017**
2018-12-17  1566.000000 1520.910034 1576.130005 1505.010010 8829800 1520.910034 -4.460051
2018-12-18  1540.000000 1551.479980 1567.550049 1523.010010 6523000 1551.479980 2.009977
2018-12-19  1543.050049 1495.079956 1584.530029 1483.180054 8654400 1495.079956 -3.635240
```

It works fine, but when it starts with AMZN pct_change, the first one is incorrect because it use the last value of AAPL.

How can I change the formula to calculate the pct_change correctly?

The solution should be this:

```
        Open    Close   High    Low Volume  Adj_Close   win
Ticker  Date                            
AAPL    2018-12-14  169.000000  165.479996  169.080002  165.279999  40703700    165.479996  NaN
2018-12-17  165.449997  163.940002  168.350006  162.729996  44287900    163.940002  -0.930622
2018-12-18  165.380005  166.070007  167.529999  164.389999  33841500    166.070007  1.299259
2018-12-19  166.000000  160.889999  167.449997  159.089996  48889400    160.889999  -3.119171
AMZN    2018-12-14  1638.000000 1591.910034 1642.569946 1585.000000 6367200 1591.910034 Nan
2018-12-17  1566.000000 1520.910034 1576.130005 1505.010010 8829800 1520.910034 -4.460051
2018-12-18  1540.000000 1551.479980 1567.550049 1523.010010 6523000 1551.479980 2.009977
2018-12-19  1543.050049 1495.079956 1584.530029 1483.180054 8654400 1495.079956 -3.635240
```

Comment: Can you check each new line to see if it starts with a date and if not, then start your algorithm over for the new Ticker.

Also, you haven't shown us the code you have so far. That would help.